# Mapping namespaces using JAXB in Java

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb, deserialization

Currently i am mapping a namespace by creating a package-info.java file for a package with the following annotation.

```
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
namespace = "http://example.com",
xmlns = {
    @XmlNs(prefix = "i",
    namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
})
```

As you can see one of my namespaces has no prefix whilst the other does, this currently works but i want another way of mapping the namespace without having to create a separate file, anybody have an idea of how i could place the namespace mapping inside my class alongside the annotations?

In my XML the namespaces declarations are inside my root element like below:

```
<RootElement xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com">...
```

My class declarations and annotations is like below for the root element.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement)
public static class RootElement{
   ........
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope the following helps:

### With `@XmlSchema`

**package-info**

```
@XmlSchema(
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        namespace = "http://example.com")
package forum20127191;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**RootElement**

```
package forum20127191;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement")
public class RootElement {

    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

### Without `@XmlSchema`

If you do not wish to specify the namespace qualification on the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation then you will need to namespace qualify each mapping to an element.  Your `RootElement` class would need to change to look like.

```
package forum20127191;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement", namespace="http://example.com")
public class RootElement {

    private String foo;

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://example.com")
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html